# Spark SQL create a boolean column based on a condition

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have this table:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | black |
| B | red |
| C | green |
| D | yellow |
| E | white |

I am interested in C and E values.
I need to write a Spark SQL query to create a new boolean column that shows the rows that I am interested in as 1 and others as 0. Like this:

| Column1 | Column2 | NewColumn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | black | 0 |
| B | red | 0 |
| C | green | 1 |
| D | yellow | 0 |
| E | white | 1 |

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a case expression in your spark sql

```sql
SELECT
   *,
   CASE 
       WHEN Column1 IN ('C','E') THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
   END AS NewColumn 
FROM
   my_table
```

Comment: Appreciate you! That makes sense. I was able to resolve my problem.

Comment: @jakhon  Great! Please remember to upvote and Mark this answer as the correct answer so that other S/O users with a similar questions will identify it as the solution